# Shopify javascript/jQuery condition for scrollTop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am making a javascript/jQuery condition to make the header drop down once a user clicks a button ("Buy Now") only when they can't see the header (200px down). My problem is that when the user scrolls more than 200px even if they scroll back up the code still exectues. Here is my code, thanks.

```
$(function() {
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(y);

    if (y >= 200) {
        $('.product__add-to-cart-button').click(function() {
            // your statements;
            $(".site-header").addClass("site-header--fixedd").removeClass("site-header--transparent");
            $("#crazy-pineapple, #coco-twist, #crunchy-joy, #nutty-chia").css('margin-top', 143);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".site-header__cart-bubble").removeClass("bubblenormal").addClass("bubblevisible");

            }, 300);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".site-header__cart-bubble").removeClass("bubblevisible").addClass("bubblenormal");
            }, 700);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".site-header").removeClass("site-header--fixedd");
                $(".site-header").addClass("site-header--fixeddd");
            }, 1200);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#crazy-pineapple, #coco-twist, #crunchy-joy, #nutty-chia").css('margin-top', 0);
                $(".site-header").addClass("site-header--transparent");
                $(".site-header").removeClass("site-header--fixedd");
                $(".site-header").removeClass("site-header--fixeddd");
            }, 1600);
        });
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few big NO's in your code.

You should **NEVER** add a event handler in a scroll/resize function! Why? Because you keep stacking them once you do the resizing/scrolling.

At the moment you apply multiply `click` events to `.product__add-to-cart-button` which I assume you don't want.

In addition there is no point to your `scroll` event at the moment. You can just create an `if` statement inside the click event if the scrollTop() is bigger than 200 and you can remove the scroll event all together.

In addition you must get the habit of caching objects if you plan to use them multiply times. Any object used more than once must be cached.

And here is how should your code look if we take in consideration all of the above remarks:

```
$(function() {
    var $win = $(window);
    var $siteHeader = $(".site-header");
    var $siteHeaderCartBuble = $(".site-header__cart-bubble");
    var $group = $("#crazy-pineapple, #coco-twist, #crunchy-joy, #nutty-chia");

    $('.product__add-to-cart-button').on('click',function() {
        if ($win.scrollTop() <= 200) {
            return false
        };

        $siteHeader
            .addClass("site-header--fixedd")
            .removeClass("site-header--transparent");

        $group.css('margin-top', 143);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $siteHeaderCartBuble
                .removeClass("bubblenormal")
                .addClass("bubblevisible");
        }, 300);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $siteHeaderCartBuble
                .removeClass("bubblevisible")
                .addClass("bubblenormal");
        }, 700);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $siteHeader
                .removeClass("site-header--fixedd")
                .addClass("site-header--fixeddd");
        }, 1200);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $group.css('margin-top', 0);
            $siteHeader
                .addClass("site-header--transparent")
                .removeClass("site-header--fixedd")
                .removeClass("site-header--fixeddd");
        }, 1600);
    });
})
```

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH, this worked. I will follow your tips.